# StringType and NoneType in python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a codebase which uses StringType and NoneType(types module) in the python2.x codebase. On porting to Python3, tests failed as the types module in Python3.x does not have the above mentioned two types.

I solved the problem by replacing them with "str" and "None" respectively. I was wondering if there is another (right)way of doing this. What I'm doing currently definitely seems to work, but I'm doubtful.

> Should I stick to the approach I have followed or is there something wrong in what I have done? If so, how do I correct it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Checking None is usually done by calling `obj is None`, while checking for string usually is `isinstance(obj, str)`. In Python 2.x to detect both string and unicode, you could use `isinstance(obj, basestring)`.

If you use `2to3`, it's enough, but if you need to have single piece of code working in both Py2 and Py3, you may end up with something like that:

```
try:
    return isinstance(obj, basestring)
except NameError:
    return isinstance(obj, str)
```

Comment: You're right, but it's generally recommended to make code which will pass through `2to3` correctly rather than making the one lot of code deal with all situations. If you just use `isinstance(obj, basestring)`, `2to3` will change it to `isinstance(obj, str)`.

Comment: Ah, ok, I had no idea about 2to3 - I just once written small library which was required to work in both of them. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: With both `basestring` and `unicode` missing from Python3, it's now very difficult to write code that works in both versions of the language.

Answer (score 7):

Where possible I would recommend that you avoid the values in `types` if their values are obvious; so for something like binding a method to an object, use `types.MethodType`, but for `types.StringTypes` use `(str, unicode)` or rather `basestring`.

For this situation, I would do this:

- Use `obj is None` or `obj is not None` rather than `isinstance(obj, NoneType)` or `not isinstance(obj, NoneType)`.
- Use `isinstance(obj, basestring)` rather than `isinstance(obj, StringTypes)`
- Use `isinstance(obj, str)` rather than `isinstance(obj, StringType)`

Then, when you're needing to distribute for Python 3, use `2to3`. Then your `basestring` will become `str` and the rest will continue to work as it did before.

(Also, bear in mind this, in particular the difference between `StringType` and `StringTypes`:

```
types.UnicodeType == unicode
types.StringType == str
types.StringTypes == (str, unicode)
```

)